# Trouble vectorizing a UDF to allow mutate() to change a dataframe

Tags: r, vectorization, user-defined-functions, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that I can use with dplyr and mutate.  In my real example, I want to pass two columns and return a value that uses ifelse statements based on each column to decide what calculation to perform.

After seeing that if-statements don't vectorize, I tried using ifthen because I though it automatically vectorized.  I still had problems and have reduced things to what now amounts to a lookup.  I have 2 skus.  Each item has a weight.  I want items that weight less than 5 lbs to be Small, and the others to be Big

```
library(dplyr)

x<- data.frame(Sku = c(9, 12), Lbs = c(9, 2))
> x
  Sku Lbs
1   9   9
2  12   2

SizeCalc <- function(Wt) 
{ ifelse (Wt <= 5, 
          Size <- "Small",
          Size <- "Big")
  return (Size)
}
```

This first item is Big, and the second is small.  But, if I run this on the full data frame, it thinks both items are big.  If I only send the second item, it knows it's small.

```
> mutate(x[1:2,], Size = SizeCalc(Lbs))
  Sku Lbs Size
1   9   9  Big
2  12   2  Big
> mutate(x[2:2,], Size = SizeCalc(Lbs))
  Sku Lbs  Size
1  12   2 Small
```

If I explicitly vectorize the function, it works:

```
> SizeCalc_v <- Vectorize(SizeCalc)
> mutate(x[1:2,], Size = SizeCalc_v(Lbs))
  Sku Lbs  Size
1   9   9   Big
2  12   2 Small
```

Do I need to always vectorize functions I want to use with mutate(), or was there something else I've left out?

After seeing the comment, I'm elaborating.  My actual function has nested ifelses that give results used in a calculation, so I can't just return the result of the ifelse.  Here's the actual function.  The inputs First and Last and dates in YYYYMM format.  I'm calculating the # of "half-years" between the dates, but Jan counts as the end of the previous year.  I have a similar problem where the result depends on how much of the original data frame I send.

```
Delta <- function(First, Last) 
{ ifelse (First%%100 <= 6, 
          F <- 2*(First%/%100) + 1, # if in 1st half of year add 1
          F <- 2*(First%/%100) + 2) # if in 2nd half of year add 2
  ifelse (Last%%100 >= 7, 
          L <- 2*(Last%/%100) + 2,  # if in 2nd half of year add 2
          ifelse (Last%%100 >= 2,
                  L <- 2*(Last%/%100) + 1, # if in Feb-Jun 1
                  L <- 2*(Last%/%100)))    # if in Jan, treat as previous year
  return (L-F)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `SizeCalc` function incorrectly. No need to assign values to a variable (`Size`) inside `ifelse`.

`ifelse` is vectorised, change your function to

```
SizeCalc <- function(Wt) ifelse(Wt <= 5, "Small","Big")
```

and now if we use `mutate`, it works as expected.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(x, Size = SizeCalc(Lbs))

#  Sku Lbs  Size
#1   9   9   Big
#2  12   2 Small
```

The more `dplyr` way is to use chaining

```
x %>% mutate(Size = SizeCalc(Lbs))
```

---

To debug more with your current function what is happening is if you do

```
ifelse(c(9, 2) <= 5, Size <- "Small", Size <- "Big")
```

and if you now check the `Size` object it has

```
Size
#[1] "Big"
```

and this value is being `return`ed from your function.

Instead what you want is

```
ifelse(c(9, 2) <= 5, Size <- "Small", Size <- "Big")
#[1] "Big"   "Small"
```

Comment: I've added to the full function to the original post to show why I don't think this resolves my problem.  Thanks the taking the time to answer.

Comment: @RickOlson it is not clear exactly how you are applying the function. Can you provide a reproducible example along with expected output?